# upload an image coming from php://input

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an image comming from an angular 8 app to php backend. I try to create the image with:

```
$str =file_get_contents('php://input');
$ext = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'];
$e = explode("/",$ext);
$ext = $e[1];
$filename = md5(time()).'.jpg';
$path = 'upload/'.$filename;
file_put_contents($path,$str);
```

the image is created but always corrupted.

Here's the header I send:

```
'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
```

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

from [`PUT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) documention.

```
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

So you can change `ext` to extension you uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ;-) The problem is still the same, the image is corrupted...

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader so I don't have own code

Comment: Here's my Request headers:
Content-Length: 437694
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
    WebKitFormBoundaryJlzcrWDWhi4zPAwC

Comment: @LaurentB so its not `put` and you cant get the file with `php://input` you must get file with `$_FILES`

Comment: @LaurentB your wlc, you can accept my answer ;) :))